# Will there be official hydro support for Ubuntu 13.10 soon?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

... Now that 13.04 is not provided with updates anymore. Or should one go back to 12.04LTS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125461/will-there-be-official-hydro-support-for-ubuntu-13.10-soon?/) by [karlelch](https://answers.ros.org/users/11556/karlelch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-02-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2014-02-02**:
This is a previous question related: http://answers.ros.org/question/117906/how-to-install-ros-on-unbuntu-1310

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hydro will never officially support 13.10, see [REP3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#hydro-medusa-aug-2013) which outlines the platforms for each distribution.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2014-02-02**:
You probably meant 13.10, right?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-02-03**:
Yup, updated.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Will there be official hydro support for Ubuntu 13.10 soon?

There was recently a [good complete discussion on ros-users](http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2014-January/068163.html) regarding `Raring` and `Saucy` support for `hydro`, and the conclusion was no.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-02-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karlelch](https://answers.ros.org/users/11556/karlelch/) on 2014-02-03**:
Thanks. I guess I'll switch back to 12.04 then...